# How to make a php-script run another php-script but with parameters

Tags: php, parameters

My webhost offers "one-click" cronjobs where you can set up a simple cronjob by pointing it to a php-file and choosing the desired run frequency. However the set-up only seems to accept regular URL's and so does not accept including various parameters for the target php-file.

I was wondering whether I could simply create a new php-file with a script that will run the target php-file including the parameters, and then let the webhost's cronjob point to the new php-file instead.

I am totally new to php, and finding out how to program a script that executes a php-file with parameters is apparently beyond my capacity.

[Background: I've installed tiny tiny rss (as a replacement for Google reader) on my hosted webpage and to ensure regular feed updates in my mobile device, running cronjob on the webpage is necessary. However, the relevant update.php file needs to run with some parameters (--feeds and --quiet), which are therefore the parameters I need to include when running the cronjob.]

Comment: There are functions that can execute a process and pass it command line arguments, but they are very very likely to have been disabled by your host. You should ask them.

Comment: If you're going to the trouble of trying to pass parameters this way, why not just include the parameters as variable declarations at the top of your script and edit them as required?

Comment: If it clarifies: the tiny tiny rss documentation for running the cronjob yourself (without the webhost's shortcut) says to use /home/user/public_html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --quiet, where these two parameters are specific to the update.php (and does not work in the short-cut cronjob). Sorry if my terminology is too imprecise - as I said: total novice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the system() function:

```
system('/usr/bin/php /home/user/public_html/tt-rss/update.php --feeds --quiet');
```

don't forget to update the path to php and the path to update.php

If it doesn't work, you could try http://feedly.com to replace Google Reader

Answer (score -1):

you can use the command shell through php to run the file :

exec("php name.php");

Works For me.